# Python FTPlib typeerror: storbinary() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to upload a file to an ftp server but it keeps coming up with the error: TypeError: storbinary() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'. Here is the code:

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP("Address","Username","Passcode")
print(ftp.getwelcome())
myfile=open("ftptest.txt","r")
ftp.storbinary("STOR ftptest.txt")
myfile.close()
ftp.cwd("")
ftp.quit()
```

Could you tell me why the error is happening and any possible solutions?

Comment: unrelated: open the file in binary mode: `'rb'`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the file object as the error message suggests:

```
ftp.storbinary("STOR ftptest.txt", myfile)
```